# Implementing fluid design on an existing page

Tags: jquery, css, fluid

I have an existing page with so many images and text on it and so many other contents.
The requirement is that i need to shrink the contents of the entire page on resizing of the window.

Is there a way that i can implement fluid design on that page using jquery without altering the current css much ?

Comment: you can add @media queries??

Comment: css is for styling the layout of an html document. If you want to shrink and resize, its css that will make the changes you need. as Burg suggests, use media queries. or use relative widths for your container/s.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following website http://scottjehl.github.io/Respond/test/test.html by minimizing and see how media queries work.Use firebug or developer tools to get the media query they are using.Hope this really helps you..

Thanks
AB